# Nobody there is called for discipline from

Tags: word-order

Is this sentence correct?

> Nobody there is called for discipline from

I mean what what order should it have becase it seems  to have been over twisted or something...

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "called for discipline", this is not a construct I would ever use. The word "from" at the end seems to have no referent. From *what*?

Comment: It's like "nobody requires discipline from anyone there". We make "anyone" the main noun doing it like "Nobody is required discipline from". I just said "call for" instead of "require".

Comment: Or maybe it should be like "Discipline isn't called for from anybody there"?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Is this a sentence you have made up or did you get it from someone else? Where did you get it?

Comment: @DonB.no, of course I've made it myself. As I have gotten from the comments no fool would have ever said this stupidity. 

Can I exchange "Nobody there is called for discipline from" for "Discipline isn't called for from anybody there"?

Comment: The last one is correct and understandable, "Discipline isn't called for from anybody there." You can use that.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko I like your sense of humor. :) And your flag.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are looking for. I would say something like: "They don't demand discipline from anyone there." Or as an alternative: "They don't require people to be disciplined there." If you want to use "call," you can say, "They don't call upon anyone there to be disciplined."

Comment: But I want to use the passive voice and "call for". Can I exchange "Nobody there is called for discipline from" for "Discipline isn't called for from anybody there"?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Yes. You would be understood if you said that.